# how can I set Enviroment Variables for data science mode of vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, data-science

I am using data science mode of vscode.

When vscode runs the jupyter kernel, can I add the desired path to PYTHONPATH of jupyter kernel?
In other cases, I used "env" of launch.json, but I can not find the way to set it up in data science mode.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. Are you trying to add to PYTHONPATH for some reason or just set it to ensure that the Interactive Python window uses a specific environment?

The simplest interpretation of the question that I can answer is that the jupyter kernel (actually it's the IPython kernel) uses the python environment set as the default for python extension, which you can set with the "Python: Select Interpreter" command. To see which interpreter is being used by the interactive window, execute this cell:

```
#%%
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Does that help?

Comment: I want to set PYTHONPATH for extra library not location of python executable file.  

I can add library path to insert sys.path.extend to python code.  
But I want to add extra library path for jupyter kernel using config file of vscode.